# about make:crud and use of yaml in routing Symfony flex

Tags: php, symfony

how to use make:crud generate routes in a .yaml?

I use Symfony since 2.3 up until 3.4 (not flex) and so became accustomed to use doctrine:generate:crud to make the skeleton of my applications.

The command doctrine:generate:crud has a parameter to specify where to define the routes (annotation, yaml, php) It seems that this was replaced by symfony/maker-bundle with make:crud which doesn't seems to have any additional parameter.

I know that that I can create a maker.yaml to configure it ( https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html ), but not found any examples of what I can do to specify how to define routes.

So the question is: **it still can be done, or they just downgraded such useful tool?**

Comment: It is a bit sad but the maker bundle only supports annotations for controller routes.  You can see the annotations being hard coded in: https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/blob/master/src/Resources/skeleton/controller/Controller.tpl.php Not a big fan of annotations myself.  On the other hand, I'm lucky enough not to have to use crud type generators in the first place.

Comment: :/ this is sad, I have a naming convention/template to route based in the user role and it is way better to do it in yaml.
Having to do it to 10+ controllers manually will be a pain